# JQuery.Dirty Fields not work on first `updateFormState` but work on second

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dirtyforms

Using jquery.dirtyFields for updating form state on button click. It worked fine on button click which passes through following code

```
$('#hidChangeBox').val(true);
$.fn.dirtyFields.updateFormState($("#formId"));
```

But it does not work fine first time on button Click. Could anyone suggest what reason it could be?

Following Link for reference: http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/dirtyFields/documentation.cfm

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the type of field? The library doesn't seem to be aware of the new field types in HTML5. i.e. input[type='number']